# Couldn't connect to Julia

Tags: julia

EDIT:
Ok, I did 2 things, I uninstalled pandas antivirus which I think had removed julia.exe as a virus.  I also uninstalled the juno/julia bundle and installed Light Table and Julia separately.  Its working now.  Thanks for trying to help everyone!
\EDIT

I'm on a windows 7 PC, I downloaded the Julia/Juno 64 bit windows bundle from http://julialang.org/downloads/.  When I try to 'evaluate' code a message pops up that says:

"Couldn't connect to Julia. Could not find command: julia"

These messages also pop up in the console when starting Julia:

(electron) ipc module is deprecated. Use ipcRenderer module instead.

Error: spawn julia ENOENT true

Thanks anyone who can help!

Comment: Are you having this problem from the julia command prompt or from Juno?

Comment: I think the better starting point for Julia is to 

 - first download a suitable [release version][1] of its own (no IDE)
 - It's very important to read Doc, you can download a pdf of [0.4 version][2]
 - walk through documentation and use Julia REPL to run sample codes

  [1]: http://julialang.org/downloads/
  [2]: http://readthedocs.org/projects/julia/downloads/pdf/release-0.4/

Answer (score 1):

I believe I remember having this issue before with Juno. The fix that I used was to use the following commands:

```
Pkg.add("Jewel")
Pkg.add("Lazy")
```

Once those two packages are installed Juno should run.

Edit:
You should be able to launch a desktop app of julia to launch julia. However if you cannot find the desktop app open a command shell and cd to the following

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Julia-yourversionnum\bin
```

and type the command

```
julia
```

then you should be able to add the packages using the commands above.

Comment: I tried running those in Juno but still it doesn't run.  Am I supposed to use them in the Julia interpreter REPL?  I don't know how to launch the interpreter.

Comment: yes that should be in the Julia interpreter, when you downloaded Julia there should have been a command prompt for Julia for windows or you can open a command prompt and change directories until you are at Julia's directory on your computer. Once there you should be able to run those commands

Comment: I cd'd into the Julia directory and entered the commands.  it returned this error message: 'Pkg.add' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: On my laptop (which was using windows 8 when I downloaded julia) has a desktop app that should automatically launch a julia shell.

Comment: if you can't find the desktop app try this: I cd'd until I got to here C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Julia-0.3.10\bin  NOTE you should put your version of julia which is likely not Julia-0.3.10. Finally once you have cd'd there launch julia by typing julia. This will launch a julia shell. Then you can use the Pkg.add commands above